# Rails: Custom Rake Task error => rake aborted! missing :controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, environment, rake-task

(RoR with Rails 3.1, gem rake 0.9.2.2)

I'm trying to run the most basic custom rake task as you can see here:

```
task :update_me => :environment do

Product.all.each do |product|
        puts product.link
end

end
```

I keep getting the error below. The task will run if I just print out hello world and take out the ":environment" part. My rake task seems to be having trouble with the  ":environment" part of this, but I need this to access my models.

```
rake aborted!
missing :controller

Tasks: TOP => update_me => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

trace:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:179:in `default_controller_and_action'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:76:in `normalize_options!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:59:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1302:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1302:in `add_route'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1282:in `decomposed_match'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1268:in `block in match'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1268:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1268:in `match'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:505:in `map_method'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:467:in `get'
/home/ubuntu/code/preevio/config/routes.rb:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
/home/ubuntu/code/preevio/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/code/preevio/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: There seems to be a routing error in your environment. What happens when you run `rake routes`?

Comment: oh there was a problem with my route file. thanks!!!

Comment: @joetesia Cool! :) I added it as answer so you can close the question.

Comment: On a side note, it's better to use `Product.find_each` instead of `Product.all.each` (performance-wise)

Answer (score 2):

The backtrace seems to indicate an error in the routes file, which is loaded when you require the environment.

In these cases, running `rake routes` will bring further information on the problem.